# creating a 32-bit virtual env in 64-bit ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, virtualenv, 32bit-64bit

I want 32-bit python on a 64-bit machine. So how to create a virtual environment where I can work on 32-bit python. I tried the following:

```
$ set CONDA_FORCE_32BIT=1
$ conda create -n py27_32 python=2.7
$ source activate py27_32
```

But after activation when I ran version check using:

```
import platform
print(platform.architecture())
```

This is the output:

```
('64bit', '')
```

Thanks in advance.